# Adding pagination to the right side of a UINavigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

A designer asked me to add pagination to a UINavigation bar in a project with its target building for ios4.3+.

I know you can add two buttons to the right side of a Navigation bar as explained here in this blog : [enter link description here](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/blog/2010/11/02/how-to-add-multiple-uibarbuttonitems-to-uinavigationbar/)

But to get the appearance requested to by the designer 
[image]

Do I need to add images to my button or is this some kind of native control(Special UISegmentedControl?) I haven't seen before? Or Just 2 custom buttons with background images.

Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the same function with a segmented control and without defining custom buttons with images.Instead of adding images for arrows i used the the corresponding Unicode chars and instantiated the segmented control with them.

```
    UISegmentedControl *toggleSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"\u25B2",@"\u25BC",nil]];

UIBarButtonItem *toggleSegmentedControlBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toggleSegmentedControl];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = toggleSegmentedControlBarItem;
```

Then your leftBarButtonItem is replaced by the segmented control.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If I undestand, you want put a image in each UIBarButtonItem and setting button status (when is clicked or normal condition). If yes, you can try this code

```
`UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImage *buttonImagePressed = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imagepressed.png"];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[myButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setImage:buttonImage forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];


UIBarButtonItem aBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];

// Create and Set the Target and Action for aButton
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`
```

Comment: no he needs two buttons that are close to each other like segmentedcontrol.If you add bar button items it leaves by default a certain amont of space between items